# URL-Based-Navigation in Android like iOS three20's TTNavigator

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Are there any similar library for `URL-Based-Navigation` like what `iOS' three20's  TTNavigator` provided?

URL-Based-Navigation is very handy and is a lot better then the Android's `intent` (if you dont need the feature for outside to call your activity)

e.g. in iOS

```
[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:
  [[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://restaurant/Chotchkie's"] 
   applyAnimated:YES]]
```

A single statement allow you to jump to any defined view, which is superb easy to use.

[1] http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-URL-Based-Navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you find this is better or faster or less cluttering than :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Make the transition from one activity to another activity stateless, like what you can do in www nowadays. Change of activity does not affect the url.

Comment: Sorry. I've just read the doc for URL-Based-Navigation and I can not see the point of this library. There seems to be a lot of people using it so I must have missed something :D You'll have to wait for someone else to answer.